# How do you save an environmental variable?

Tags: command-line, bash

Trying to save an environmental variable.

```
cd ~
mkdir Projects
export PROJDIR=/Users/David/Projects
cd ~
cd $PROJDIR //can execute.
cd ..
open .bash_profile //was told this was the file you add the variable to.
```

Then terminal tells me there is nothing with that name.
To check

```
ls -a
```

And there are two files with bash .bash_history and .bashsessions 
.bash_history isn’t executable and when I open .bashsessions I’m not sure how I’d add

```
export PROJDIR=/Users/$USER/Projects
```

to the file. So that doesn't seem right either.

Answer (score 3):

‘export’ doesn't write anything to file. [It's for making variables available to subprocesses.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7411455/1549818)

If you've never written anything to .bash_profile, it's unsurprising that it doesn't exist, since it's not created for you. You'll need to create it yourself and write that line within.

For example, `touch ~/.bash_profile` (to create the file) then edit it in an editor of your choice such as TextEdit (open using Finder or `open -e ~/.bash_profile`). Alternatively, `nano ~/.bash_profile`. Paste in `export PROJDIR=/Users/$USER/Projects` and save the file, then reopen your shell or source the profile.

Comment: You can write it to .bashrc as well.

Answer (score 2):

Redirection is one of the simplest ways to create a file with text or append a file with text. Standard output is redirected with the `>` symbol or appended to a file with `>>`.

In your case, you want the string `export PROJDIR=/Users/$USER/Projects` added to `.bash_profile`. We will protect the string with single (strong) quotes, so `$USER` is not expanded.

```
cd  # no need for the tilde (~)
echo 'export PROJDIR=/Users/$USER/Projects' >>.bash_profile
```

A single `>` will overwrite any text in a file, so use `>>` and append the text for safety. It would benefit you to learn one of the three visual editors (vi/vim, emacs, nano) supplied in macOS.